# Why did the movies of James Bond replace SMERSH with SPECTRE?

Tags: analysis, james-bond

While SPECTRE also has a main role in Ian Fleming's James Bond novels, the real archenemy was SMERSH, a Russian counterspy organisation. But for the movies SPECTRE and Blofeld was almost exclusively the main antagonist.

Given that many movies were filmed during the Cold war when the Evil Russian™ was a valid target, why did the producers prefer a secret terrorist/criminal organisation? Is there any reason mentioned by the producers? (With citations, please no speculations).

Comment: Because SMERSH is a fairly rubbish name? Nomen est omen, after all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you need to know is here, it was Fleming himself who suggested the change whilst working for producer Kevin McClory on the script for what would become **Thunderball** (book and film)  prior to making the first film Dr No:

[Reflections on the Origins of SPECTRE](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/literary007.com/2015/10/28/reflections-on-the-origins-of-spectre/amp/)

> In a memo dated 15 June 1959 Fleming wrote that it would be unwise to directly identify Russia as the enemy: ‘Since the film will take about two years to produce, and peace might conceivably break out in the meantime, this should be avoided’. **He suggested instead that the villainous plot be the work of an international terrorist group known by the acronym SPECTRE**.

Also :

> Fleming claims that he closed down SMERSH in his novels and invented SPECTRE to reflect what he saw as a partial thawing of the Cold War. (Bond himself admits in Thunderball that ‘with the Cold War easing off, it was not like the old days’.) **The reality was that, as Fleming knew, Britain’s ability to act as an effective force in the international struggle against ‘Redland’ was, by this time, stretching the bounds of credulity**. Fleming’s Playboy interview also suggested a literary logic behind the change, proposing that SPECTRE represented a ‘much more elastic fictional device’. Put simply, **the new organisation appeared to offer more wide-ranging potential for an engaging thriller narrative, not least because the master-criminal or super-villain now truly represented a universal, international threat to humanity. He is no longer simply an organ or agent of state**. Blofeld’s organisation, we are told, is a ‘private enterprise for private profit’ – in the parlance of modern intelligence agencies SPECTRE is a potent, hostile ‘non-state actor’.

Comment: Nice find and good article. Accepted.

Comment: Plus, wouldn't a worldwide evil organization be more evil than just a Russian evil organization?

Comment: "not least because the master-criminal or super-villain now truly represented a universal, international threat to humanity. He is no longer simply an organ or agent of state" - yepp.